# Jquery DataTables default 'dom' order update on preInit when writing an extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Below code works fine. I can write my extension logics in _constructor and extended defaults will get overwrite in all the tables.

```
(function(window, document, undefined){

var factory = function($, DataTable) {
    "use strict";

    $.extend(true, DataTable.defaults, {
        dom: '<"dataTablesTop"' +
            'f' +
            '<"dataTables_toolbar">' +
            '>' +
            'rt' +
            '<"dataTablesBottom"' +
            'lip' +
            '>'
    });

    myExtension.prototype = {
            _constructor: function(){
                  ....
            }
    }

    ....

    return myExtension;

})(window, document);
```

But my expected out come is to apply the extended overwrites based on a config value passed along with the DataTables initialization.

```
var oTable = $('#table').DataTable({
     myExtension: true
});
```

Ideally it should be something like,

```
(function(window, document, undefined){

var factory = function($, DataTable) {
    "use strict";

    myExtension.prototype = {
            _constructor: function(){
                if(settings.myExtension){
                   $.extend(true, DataTable.defaults, {
                       dom: '<"dataTablesTop"' +
                            'f' +
                            '<"dataTables_toolbar">' +
                            '>' +
                            'rt' +
                            '<"dataTablesBottom"' +
                            'lip' +
                            '>'
                   });
                }
            }
    }

    .....

    return myExtension;


})(window, document);
```

Anybody have an idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this isn't possible at the moment. DataTables initialize dom elements before 'preInit' callback. So looks like need to push/inject additional elements in the construction stage.

Reference: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25342/init-dt-is-not-fired-before-the-first-xhr-event#Comment_69825